# Cardinality of a set S which contains twice differentiable function with some conditions.

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be the set of twice differentiable function on $[a, b]$ satisfying $f''(x) = e^x f(x)$ with $f(a)=f(b)=0$ then cardinality of S will be.

1. Finite
2. Infinite
3. Infinite but countable
4. Infinite but uncountable .

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Also, doesn't 'infinite' contain both 'infinite but countable' and 'infinite but uncountable'?

Comment: @Mattos yeah I tried. Zero is the member of S. Further more I'm not getting any point.

Comment: @Mattos  Also, doesn't 'infinite' contain both 'infinite but countable' and 'infinite but uncountable'?

Comment: Hint: Try an easy case first. Suppose $f>0$ on $(a,b).$ Then $f''>0$ on $(a,b).$ Is that possible?